# Сравнение таблиц в python

Tags: python, excel

Есть проблема в написании кода, необходимо сравнить две таблицы в excel где есть столбцы: артикул, цена.
Нужно найти пересекающиеся значения и записать их в новую таблицу с данными пересекающихся артикулов и цена из первого прайса и цена из второго прайса. Уникальные значения не учитываем.

Comment: Ну так пусть тот, кому необходимо, и пишет. От нас-то что надо?

Comment: Это не биржа фриланса, покажите пример вашего кода с описанием того что не получается либо того на чем запнулись

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Comment: Вам что на курсах про стаковерфлоу рассказали, а вы не всё запомнили? Правила читайте.